# Suitable chart library for dynamic data?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a suitable JavaScript charting library that will work well with being generated with data pulled from an API using Ajax/JSON. I'll be primarily using line, bar and pie charts.

Any library that is straightforward to use, has good documentation and will allow me to have animated graphs is also a plus.

What is my best option in this scenario?

Comment: Hi Connor, since this question was put on hold, you should repost it on StackExchange's [Software Recommendation site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague - though from personal experience, I have found [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [canvas.js](http://canvasjs.com) (preferring the former) to be easy to use - they have detailed documentation, easy-to-use code formats and also available animations when the graphs are changed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

**D3.JS**

Have you seen [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)?

As far as I know, it is the MOST flexible charting library.

Checkout the examples here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

---

**Highcharts**

The other one that I have used is [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts). Its not open source though and it is not free for commercial purposes. However, it is very easy to use.

---

**Google Visualization / Google Charts**

You may also use [Google Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/) but it doesnt work offline (they dont allow you to download the library, sadly). But its easy to use.

All of the 3 libraries mentioned above provide line, bar and pie charts, with animation and very well documented.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As said by @think123 I am also a fan of `chart.js` however it is limited in the sense of displaying actual data within the graphs themselves. [Flot](https://code.google.com/p/flot/) is also highly praised and does not have the limitations of `chart.js` - the hover effect is similar to Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3)?

D3 stands for Data-Driven Documents, but what it really means, is that it is a visualization library, that ultimately, like any other js visualization library, draw things on canvas.

*Example*: Some of the things that can be made using it are beautiful. Such as [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html)